# invalidate metadata Unrecognized command in impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, impala

Invalidate metadata command is not working in Impala Shell v1.0.

Using Cloudera 5.2.

Shell version: Impala Shell v1.0
Server version: impalad version 2.0.0-cdh5 RELEASE

Below is the error:

```
[X.X.X.X:21000] > refresh;
RPC Error: Deprecated RPC; please update your client
[X.X.X.X:21000] > invalidate metadata;
Unrecognized command
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to upgrade your `impala-shell`. From the [INVALIDATE METADATA documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html):

> The INVALIDATE METADATA statement is new in Impala 1.1 and higher